# Move to Start of Line in Terminal.app

Tags: macos, terminal

Is there a quick key combo that will allow me after typing some stuff in the OSX terminal to move back to the beginning of that line?  I have tried different things, and was wondering if there is a way without setting up something that is custom.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> moves to the beginning of the line, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> to the end of the line.

Comment: BTW, it also works in any Cocoa control (text area, etc.)

Comment: Haha.  That easy, huh?  Thanks.  My Linux habits and <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> from the OSX GUI made me scratch my head.

Comment: why, my god? why?

Comment: Follow-up question (which answers @BrunoJCM's question/plea) - does Terminal provide any other emacs-compatible keybindings?